# Sharepoint 2013 - Export Excel with external lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, export

I can't export to excel from external lists. The button is disabled in the ribbon.

It works fine for other lists on the same site with the same user, but for external it is disabled.

Is there a specific right to grant for the external list?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Export the external list to Excel**

Navigate to the SharePoint site that contains the list.

Click the name of the SharePoint list on the Quick Launch, or on the Settings menu  Office 365 Settings button , click Site contents or View All Site Content, and then in the appropriate list section, click the name of the list.

Click List and then click Export to Excel.

By default, this capability is enabled on external lists, but it can be disabled by a system administrator.

If you are prompted to confirm the operation, click OK.

In the File Download dialog box, click Open.

If you are prompted whether to enable data connections on your computer, click Enable if you believe the connection to the data on the SharePoint site is safe to enable.

An Excel Table is created with a data connection based on a web query file. The columns in the exported table are determined by the current external list view. The external data exported is determined by the filters defined on the external content type and in the external list view, and the language settings for the SharePoint site. Any page limits are ignored.

[Export an external list to Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-an-external-list-to-Excel-fcbb5cdc-cf49-4131-8294-21bc25e66952)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do you enable the button for external lists ?